# RunTime Error : Class not found at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, runtime-error

I ran into the following error:

```
core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Class not found

at c (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)
at processMessage (cordova.js:1114)
at processMessages (cordova.js:1137)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4629)
at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
at polyfills.js:3
```

Comment: I slightly improved formatting, but in order for people to be able to help you, you should look into [mcve] and further enhance your question, for example by showing us the code that leads to the error! It is very hard to diagnose code only from error messages!

Comment: did you used any custom plugin in your app ? its related to your plugin which unable to find method.